# JavaScript for-loop loops only once when comparing i to an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Full code at: https://jsbin.com/sikeqizoda/1/edit?js,console

and the problem loop has a /**************.....*/ before and after it.

I'm doing one of the projects on freeCodeCamp and I'm encountering an issue where I have this for-loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++) {
    newArr.push("M");
}
```

in which I'm comparing an array element, in this case, `arr[i] = 3`, with `typeof` being `number`, and where `i` also has `typeof = number`. Again, in this situation, `arr[i] = 3`, and if I run the code as above, it's supposed to loop 3 times, but only loops once (only one "M" is pushed into my newArr array).

But, if I put the number 3 in place of arr[i]:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newArr.push("M");
}
```

it loops 3 times as I want it to.

I have tried putting a `console.log(arr[i])` underneath there and it logs `3`.

`console.log(i) logs 0`.

and `newArr` becomes `['M']`.

I've also tried changing `arr[i]` to `parseInt(arr[i])`, and `console.log(parseInt(arr[i]) == 3)` returns true! It's so confusing, why does '3' work, but `arr[i]` which is equivalent doesn't?

I don't understand what the issue is. Could someone please help?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've got your outer `while` loop iterating over `i`, then you declare multiple inner loops, also iterating over `i`, and the two are conflicting. *Always* use different variables for nested loops:

```js
let one = { 0: "I", 1: "X", 2: "C", 3: "M" }
let four = { 0: "IV", 1: "XL", 2: "CD" }
let five = { 0: "V", 1: "L", 2: "D" }
let nine = { 0: "IX", 1: "XC", 2: "CM" }

function consecutiveZerosAfter(index, arr) {
  let numZeros = 0;
  for (let i = index + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
      numZeros += 1;
    } else {
      return numZeros
    }
  }
  return numZeros
}

function arrayToRoman(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  let counter = 0;

  let i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
      i++;
    } else {
      if (arr[i] >= 1 && arr[i] <= 3) {
        switch (consecutiveZerosAfter(i, arr)) {
          case 0:
            for (let n = 0; n < arr[i]; n++) {
              newArr.push("I");
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            for (let n = 0; n < arr[i]; n++) {
              newArr.push("X");
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            for (let n = 0; n < arr[i]; n++) {
              newArr.push("C");
            }
            break;
            /****************************************************************************************/
          case 3:
            for (let n = 0; n < arr[i]; n++) {
              newArr.push("M");
            }
            break;
            /***************************************************************************************/
        }
      } else if (arr[i] == 4) {

      } else if (arr[i] >= 5 && arr[i] <= 8) {

      } else if (arr[i] == 9) {

      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  return newArr
}

console.log(arrayToRoman([3, 0, 0, 0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

Correct code:

```
for (let j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++) {
    newArr.push("M");
}
```

**Long answer:**

The issue is that in the for loop you are using the variable named "i" and you access the element of the array with the same variable.

When you do let i = 0 the value of the "i" variable is going to be 0, so on the first iteration of the loop you will access arr[0], and it will provide an other solution.

The answer is to use other variable name in the for loop like "j" as showed in the short answer.

The variable of the loop will be a local variable, so you can't access it from outside of the loop, so if you use "j" as the loop variables for all cases than itt will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the variable that you are defining in for-loop (let i=0) is shadowing the variable of parent, you may want to give different name to the variable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, ideally you should different variables for each of the nested loops as that would make your code easier to reason with. BUT, in your case, if you really wanted you could avoid the issue by doing something like this ->

```js
    const current = arr[i];
    for (let i = 0; i < current; i++) {
       newArr.push("M");
    }
```

This is just to clearly demonstrate the actual issue with your code, actual implementation should still try to use a different variable like `j`